# Stumped - part identification

Tags: dc, identification, remote-control

My nephews recently gave me back my old Remco Thunderhawk RC racing boat and asked me to "fix it". I've dabbled in some electronics but nothing in the RC world. My first step is to identify these parts, and then find a way to test their functionality. I've got them all figured out except this one:

[image]

What is it and how to read it?

Comment: What comes to mind is the radio-frequency part of a super-regenerative receiver. I wouldn't mess with it unless you have equipment to measure frequency (possibly 27 MHz or 45 MHz). The receiving antenna (an open-end wire) is often connected to this coil.

Comment: The functionality tests are best done by verifying the *function of the circuit the parts are in*. This requires understanding the circuit first. Testing each individual part may not help you if the failure is a cracked track, or even something outside of the circuit. Or even an operator error (say, does the transmitter even transmit at the right frequency?).

Comment: While we can make a good **guess** at which part you're asking about, it would be far better for you to clearly indicate which part you're specifically asking about, rather than leaving it to us to guess which of the 30, or so, parts which are visible in your image is the one you mean. Indicating which part you're asking about can be done by drawing a red circle around that part in the image. Alternately, in this case, there's a marking on the part which you are *most likely* interested in, "K6170", which you could mention to indicate that's the part you want to identify.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you're talking about the device in the center of the photo, it's an adjustable inductor. It's been adjusted during manufacture (using equipment you don't have) and glued (maybe with wax) in place. This is done to account for variations between different parts in manufacture, including the inductor itself.

The other parts are electrolytic capacitors, resistors, and some mylar capacitors with some (likely) TO92 transistors visible.

If you're going to have success at fixing it, I suggest looking at mechanical failures first (cracked circuit board is likely with those paper-based phenolic boards). None of those parts is at all likely to have failed (the electrolytics are the most likely, and even that is not that likely). Randomly removing parts and testing them is more likely to break something else and render the board permanently unusable. Definitely don't go moving the adjustment screw in the inductor.

Comment: The wax was leftover from melting it off the underside of the board. The manufacturer used it to seal the components into a box to avoid any water introduction.

Comment: @JBL Still: don't adjust anything that can be adjusted unless you got the equipment to do it. It's a radio receiver, and the coils would be parts of various filters. It's unlikely that it got out of alignment. 50+ year old vacuum tube radios usually are out of alignment today because someone tweaked them without know-how, not because the coils or mica caps drifted. I'd place 90% likelihood of the failure being mechanical. Do *not* remove any components unless you *first* identify that they have failed. Given little RF experience, I highly suggest reverse engineering the circuit first.